# ClearInterval isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a function of a way to stop a process of my script. It's about a script that has 16 pictures, every five seconds one random pic is chosen. And if you chose that pic(by a submit button below) the random pic 'choser' needs to stop.

Everything is working, I can't find how to make setInterval stop, I'm using clearInterval but It won't 'reset' the timer nor do anything. Even If I put clearInterval after setInterval It won't work :-(

```
 function highlight() { 
var timerId = 0;
var $divs = $('.cell').removeClass('redborder');
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length);
$divs.eq(random).addClass('redborder');

$('#submit').show();

    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('p').empty();
        if($('#plaatje1').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 1</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje2').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 2</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje3').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 3</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje4').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 4</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje5').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 5</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje6').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 6</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje7').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 7</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje8').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 8</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje9').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 9</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje10').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 10</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje11').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 11</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje12').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 12</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje13').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 13</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje14').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 14</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje15').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 15</p>");
        }
        if($('#plaatje16').hasClass("redborder") == true)
        {
            $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 16</p>");
        }

    });
}
$('#submit').click(function(){
    clearInterval(timerId);
});
timerId = setInterval(function () {
  highlight();
}, 1000);
```

This is my JS/Jquery part. I don't think the HTML part is needed, but for the ones that need it:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="randompic.js"></script> <title>Versie 1</title> </head>   <div id="content">
            <h1>Random plaatjes</h1>
                <div class="pics">
                    <div class="heading">
                    Random plaatjes om de seconden
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje1">
                                Plaatje 1
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje2">

                                Plaatje 2
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje3">

                                Plaatje 3
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje4">

                                Plaatje 4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje5">

                                Plaatje 5
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje6">

                                Plaatje 6
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje7">

                                Plaatje 7
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje8">

                                Plaatje 8
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje9">

                                Plaatje 9
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje10">

                                Plaatje 10
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje11">

                                Plaatje 11
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje12">

                                Plaatje 12
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje13">

                                Plaatje 13
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje14">

                                Plaatje 14
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje15">

                                Plaatje 15
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" id="plaatje16">

                                Plaatje 16
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="textarea">
                </div>
                   <div id="submit" class="submit">
                   <button type="submit" id="button" name="submitt">Uitleg</button>
                   </div>
```

Thank you very much for helping in advance! I'm very sorry for the misspellings and grammar mistakes, English isn't my mother tongue.

Comment: Your code seems to work. [This fiddle shows that when you click the button the timer (recording in the console log) stops](http://jsfiddle.net/0ysvt1xL/5/). Am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your event handlers are written inside the highlight function.. Splitting all of 'em apart did the trick for me..

```
 function highlight() {

     var timerId = 0;
     var $divs = $('.cell').removeClass('redborder');
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length);

     $divs.eq(random).addClass('redborder');
     console.log($divs.eq(random));

     $('#submit').show();
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#button').click(function () {
         $('p').empty();

         if ($('#plaatje1').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 1</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje2').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 2</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje3').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 3</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje4').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 4</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje5').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 5</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje6').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 6</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje7').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 7</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje8').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 8</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje9').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 9</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje10').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 10</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje11').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 11</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje12').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 12</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje13').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 13</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje14').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 14</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje15').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 15</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje16').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 16</p>");
         }

     });

     $('#submit').click(function () {
         clearInterval(timerId);
     });
 });

 timerId = setInterval(function () {
     highlight();
 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides your actual problem, you have a serious scope problem.

In highlight, you declared `var timerId` and this variable is never used in your function highlight. At the end of the function the variable "dies".

You also created an other variable with

```
timerId = setInterval()
```

But this time it is a global scope variable (because you did not put var in front). This timerId is different from your highlight's timerId.

And in `clearInterval(timerId);`, it is the global scope timerId which is called.

Your code should be working, unless you didn't show all the javascript and have some other scope conflicts.

You should now put all your code inside a

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timerId;

    //All your code with jquery hasClass/append
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        clearInterval(timerId);
    });
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
        highlight();
    }, 1000);
});
```

except your `function highlight()`. And declare a `var timerId` 
Learn more about scopes here : http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/